# Test Gearman/MySQL - Persistence Layer

Tags: php, mysql, gearman, drizzle

Running Fedora, PHP/Gearman/MySQL/Drizzle.

Built Gearman/Drizzle from source, and have the process running on a linux/fedora box. I created the mysql test table, and can see that the Gearman Daemon instance can access/interface with the mysql service. I'm running the Gearman and mysql processes on the same box, using TCP.

When Gearman is started, and points to the MySQL account, I can see the initial select statements in the DEBUG information that's displayed as the Gearman process runs.

However, I'm not sure what I need to do to actually test that a job from the Client is stored in the mysql Table.

I created a test client that replicates the Gearman Client/Worker "Review" test, that normally works if the worker is running, and ran the client without the worker. I see in the DEBUG process that the client connects with the Gearman daemon, but when I examine the mysql table, nothing is in the table.

So my question really boils down to determining what I need to do to actually be able to see/ensure that jobs/data is really written to the actual mysql table.

Is there a given flag, method to call somewhere to establish that data is to be stored in the mysql table if not processed by the worker? Shouldn't a job be stored in the table, and then removed once it's processed? Or am I missing something in the flow?

Comment: I am not sure how the flows works exactly, but I would suggest submitting a job (without the worker), and then checking the job queue via the gearmand administrative protocol. If it is in the queue there, it should also be in the table.

Answer (score 1):

http://gearman.org/manual/job_server/#persistent_queues

I guess what you are looking for is:

```
gearmand --queue-type=mysql --mysql-host=hostname
```